# Oracle weblogic access control 11g

Tags: oracle, rest, access-control, weblogic11g

Just I have installed Oracle Weblogic Server and configured RESTFul Service. Developer can able use in office network but when I placed it in proxy server then It is supporting.

As per discussed with developer, need to set cross domain access control security. Can anybody help me how to I can set that from Oracle weblogic Administrator control?

Client side they are using javascript & actionscript to call that service.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying to use SOAP UI to test the service through the proxy service and see what the behavior is.  You might want to change the proxy server to not cache the result from the URL during testing.

You can use web.xml to configure security roles and map them to WLS credentials/roles.  If you have added a username and password then you should be able to test this from SOAPUI.